# Exchange Particle between an Electron Neutrino and Neutron?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, weak-interaction

How can a neutrino turn a neutron into a proton? This is the equation,
$$ \nu_e + n \to p + e^- \,.$$

If you draw the Feynnmann Diagram which I attempted here, ["Diagram"](http://sketchtoy.com/58091388) there isn't an exchange that could transfer the positive charge from neutron to the proton? Since $\nu_e$ and Neutron are neutral, where does this reaction gain its charge? I don't get this.

Comment: At the vertex level this is $\nu_e + d \to u + e^-$, but in either case the total charge is conserved (that is, it's the same after the interaction as before).

Answer (score 2):

As it is a weak interaction,  your particle can be a $W^+$ or $W^-$ (depending on which direction it goes in time).

Answer (score 2):

> How can a neutrino turn a neutron into a proton?

For example, an electron neutrino in the vicinity of a neutron 'emits' a virtual $W^+$ thus becoming an electron (the $W^+$ has +1 electric charge and up/anti-down weak isospin charge) .

The virtual $W^+$ is 'absorbed' by a valence $d$ quark within the neutron thus becoming a $u$ quark and the neutron is now a proton.

[image]
<sub>(source: [a-levelphysicstutor.com](http://www.a-levelphysicstutor.com/images/nuclear/feynman03.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The exchange particle is a W-boson, as it must be at a neutrino--charged-lepton vertex.